# Reboot after power failure

Tags: windows-xp, reboot

REBOOTING PROBLEM

A few days ago I finished using my computer system, disconnected from the Internet, and turned my monitor off.  When I returned home I found my monitor turned on and displaying a blue screen with the Microsoft Flag logo and the words “Windows is starting up”.  I did some checking and discovered there had been a hiccup in the power grid somewhere because my microwave ovens kept flashing the word Clock.

I have a UPS between the wall outlet and my computer system (monitor, hard drive, printers, etc.).  After quite some time had passed it was obvious windows was not starting up .  I pressed the button on the front of my hard drive (tower) to turn the system off.  Didn’t work.  The system appeared frozen at the blue screen I just described.

I turned my attention to the UPS.  It had a green light displayed.  I toggled the On/Off button to shut the power off.  The UPS light went from green to red but this time the unit made a series of fast, tiny shrieks.  And the On/Off button stayed depressed.  The computer system powered down, I fiddled with the On/Off button, and it popped back up after a bit.  With the red light glowing on the UPS and my system shut down I re-pressed the On/Off button on the UPS.  The light went green but the button again stayed depressed instead of popping right back up.  I turned on the system via the button on the front of my tower.  Everything powered up.  The monitor screen showed the Dell logo, then a black screen, then a blue screen with the above described flag and wording.  But the system would go no farther.  It hung up on that blue screen just the way it was when I returned home.  Not wanting to do anything more with the UPS I used the tower button to turn the computer off, then back on again.  As the monitor displayed various screens I pressed F12 and from the menu displayed I did a reboot from C drive.  Once again the system hung up at the same blue screen.

The UPS was removed, my system was plugged into the wall outlet, and a chain of endeavors failed to get things back to normal. F8 was used at one of the reboot attempts and “Last known good configuration” was selected.  That option was used a few times but the system hangs up each time at the blue screen described above.  Then we went to the F8 menu option of Safe Mode and used System Restore---several times.  The System Restore works.  But it only works one time.  By that I mean my system can once again be used but if a reboot is done, the computer once again hangs up on that blue screen.  No normal reboot works.  To get my system up and running so I can use it, System Restore must first be used.  It is now the only way I can do a reboot of the system.

Chkdsk was run and it worked its way thru 5 different things.  Nothing wrong was found, no error messages came up, and the system still hangs up on the blue screen.  Never once during all these various attempts has any error message of any kind been displayed.

Do you know how to fix this problem of not being able to do a normal reboot after what was apparently an electrical event that fried the UPS?  We want very much to avoid a fresh install of Windows XP.

My computer is a Dell, with a Celeron processor.  For security I have Spybot, CCleaner, Microsoft Security Essentials, and PS Tools firewall.  A number of scans with Spybot, CCleaner, and Security Essentials found no virus, malware, or spyware.  I am using Windows XP Home Edition, SP3.

Hope you can help,
annie

Comment: the UPS could just have a dead battery. what you decribe in the 4th paragraph sounds like a driver that is again reinstalling, rendering the system unbootable again. Mabey some piece of hardware is acting up and when its driver loads you get the blue screen. I also wonder if the Motherboards CMOS is reset, or if things are proper way back there.  So back to the start, get into your bios and set all that stuff, then remove any unnessisary hardware. ummm then ???

Comment: Test your memory modules....http://www.memtest.org/